# How to display millions of markers on google map (Using Web GL instead of Google Map Marker) with tool tips info on every marker when clicked?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, opengl-es, webgl, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to make a web page which displaying a google map with so many markers (can be up to millions of markers) that looked up from data like json.
I try to make it using "google.maps.Marker" but it went very slowly (can be hang) on map rendering when there are so many markers. Then I found that it can be solved by using WEB GL
to render those markers on map like colored points on map. For now, I can make it until that step. 
But there are still some problem I got, like below:

1. Right now I draw markers on map using Web GL like colored points, you can see like this link http://psousa.net/demos/webgl/ (I learned from it). How to change that point shape into triangle shape or circle shape instead of point/rectangle shape like that?
2. When every point of markers is clicked, there must be a mouse down event that will show some informations about that point (like name, description, etc.). How to implement that mouse event on every single of marker using Web GL?

Comment: At a very high level: To draw a shape, either use more triangles, or a texture with the bitmap picture you want.

To do hit testing, you can render a *second* off-screen version, with a different color for each marker. Then use gl.readPixels() at the location of the mouseclick, to find out what (if anything) got clicked.

Comment: (Or, you can use a "kd tree" to pretty easily search millions of points for which is closest to your click, working backward from click.xy, position, and zoom.)

Comment: Thank you Mr David for your answer, what id kd tree? is that a part of WEB GL or another alternative way?
Do you have any sample pages for me?

Comment: A kd tree is a way to "sort spatial data", a "K-dimensional tree". The gist is to first divide everything in half in the X axis. Then, each of those to halves is divided in half in the Y axis. Then each of those 4 sets again in the X, all the way down. So searching for any spot is log2(n) down the tree, pretty quick. Takes some work up front. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree. hope that helps!